# Using facebook graph api to read photo tags

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am building a website using React and Redux to search facebook photos through tags like my Friends name or by location. User needs to login with facebook so that the application can read its pictures. A user simply puts in the search filters like Tagged users or the location of the picture and my app will show results based on the filters. This will help to find old photos with friends which sometimes get lost on social media due to a large number of photos present(Uploaded or Tagged)

I am trying to fetch mutual photos of me and my friends using my access token and trying to read the tags present in the photos through API but the Response contains only my name in the tags and not other people who are tagged in that photo.

Is there any way to fetch the users who are tagged on a photo uploaded? Any help is appreciated.

[Graph api link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/photo)

Comment: you should provide sample code of what you already tried or even screen shot, that will make finding the error more easier and faster .

Answer (score 0):

Access to any data involving your friends is only possible if those friends specifically authorized your App too. You cannot even get an ID of a friend if he did not authorize your App.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in order to access involving your friend to authorize your app. But from the details i can see that,

"A user access token may read a photo that the current user is tagged in if they have granted the user_photos or user_posts permission. However, in some cases the photo's owner's privacy settings may not allow your application to access it."

Note: Just need to verify users privacy setting once again.